# Travis stages for multiple OS

Tags: travis-ci

I'm setting up a `.travis.yml` where I need to 
- Build on two platforms
- Deploy after all the builds completed

I started by creating a `matrix` for building

```
language: cpp
matrix:
  include:
    - os: osx
      osx_image: xcode10.1
      script:
      - "./Travis/build-osx.sh"

    - os: linux
      dist: trusty
      script:
        - "./Travis/build-linux.sh"
```

This runs correctly the two builds in parallel. The question is how can I add a `stage` that will run once the two builds completed.

This [jobs documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages/) uses stages but it does not seem to work when I use a `matrix`

Answer (score 8):

So I managed to do this by having three stages, two having the same name. The stages with the same name run in parallel

```
language: cpp

notifications:
  email: false

jobs:
  include:
  - stage: build
    os: osx
    osx_image: xcode10.1
    script:
      - "./Travis/build-osx.sh"

  - stage: build        
    os: linux
    dist: trusty

    script:
      - ./Travis/build-linux.sh

  - stage: Deploy      
      - ./Travis/binaries-upload.sh
```